# Least action principle and uniform motion

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, boundary-conditions, variational-principle

I'm trying to apply the principle of least action to the case of a uniform motion under no potential. Assume the object starts with initial velocity $v_0$, moving from point $A$ to point $B$. We know that the motion is a uniform one with the object reaching the point $B$ after a time $T=\frac{AB}{v_0}$. The associated action is $S_1=\int_0^T\frac{mv^2}{2}dt=\frac{mv_0}{2}AB$.

Now consider a path where the velocity is reduced suddenly from $v_0$ to $v_1<v_0$ near the initial point $A$. The associated action would be $S_2\approx\frac{mv_1}{2}AB$ which is smaller than $S_1$.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least action (or stationary action) means least along all those paths *which begin and end at the given points*, and that means the given times as well as locations. If a path sets out with a smaller speed then in order to arrive at the final location at the required time, it will have to go faster at some stage. The integral of kinetic energy over that path is larger than the integral over the constant-velocity path.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is that the new path violates the boundary conditions (BCs) of the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle), usually [Dirichlet BCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition).

Comment: Does rendering the sudden change to a smooth one satisfy the Dirichlet BCs?

Comment: Oh, it means that the path chosen must not change the total time $T$ needed to travel from $A$ to $B$, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The change in velocity would require an extra force which would change the Lagrangian. Even if the sudden force was not so sudden the Lagrangian would still change due to this interaction.